# UWP: Set text to bold in TreeNode

Tags: c++, text, uwp, treeview, bold

I am following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view) to implement a  `TreeView` in a `Universal Windows Platform` app in `C++`. I have successfully been able to create a tree view with one node using the following codes:

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeSolution"></TreeView>
```

C++:

```
TreeViewNode ^treeNode = ref new TreeViewNode();
treeNode->Content = "Hello";
treeSolution->RootNodes->Append(treeNode);
```

Now, I want to set the text to bold. I tried the following:

```
TextBlock ^textBlock = ref new TextBlock();
textBlock->Text = "Hello";
textBlock->FontWeight = Windows::UI::Text::FontWeights::Bold;
treeNode->Content = textBlock;
treeSolution->RootNodes->Append(treeNode);
```

The code displays `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock` instead of `Hello` in bold.

The documentation says that `In Windows 10, version 1803, you have to retemplate the TreeView control and specify a custom ItemTemplate if your content is not a string.` It then gives a complex example using the Music and Picture library.

Could somebody provide a simple example of how to display the text in bold? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a custom style for the whole control in XAML to be able to set the `TreeViewItemDataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemDataTemplate">
    <Grid Height="44">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Content}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
            FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="TreeView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl"
                              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
                              CanDragItems="True"
                              AllowDrop="True"
                              CanReorderItems="True">
                    <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <ContentThemeTransition />
                            <ReorderThemeTransition />
                            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                </TreeViewList>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! For others having the same problem, I have added these codes within `<Page.Resources> </Page.Resources>`.  I also had to clean the project.